# How can I input such 'dot' or 'star' in emacs?

Tags: emacs, gnus

(setq gnus-sum-thread-tree-root "●")
(setq gnus-sum-thread-tree-false-root "☆")

thanks.

Comment: Please post the code that you have tried!

Answer (score 2):

If you know either their Unicode code point, or their official Unicode name, you can use `C-x 8 RET`.

Answer (score 1):

Turn on Egg input method (M-x toggle-input-method), which is usually bound to "C-\". Then, type "z!" for "●", "z6" for "☆".